# Is it grammatically correct to write "I feel I'm part of this world/family/group/movement..." or do I have to use "feel like"

Tags: grammar

So I want to write "I feel I'm part of this world" in an essay/poem kind of text.

I don't feel like writing "feel like" instead, because to me it seems to indicate that this feeling can be false, or some kind of comparison.

I want to say something more along the lines of "I know I'm part of this world", but indicate an emotional or sensual context, instead of an intellectual one.

So, can I say "I feel I am..."??

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the word "like," and the phrase carries a slightly different meaning if you do, as you suspected in your question.

Per [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feel), "like" can mean

> to be conscious of an inward impression, state of mind, or physical condition

In this definition, "like" functions as an *intransitive* verb, so it requires either an adjective or a prepositional phrase to describe *how* one feels, as you did when you wrote "I feel **like** I am part..."

However, feel can also be a *transitive* verb, as in this definition:

> to have one's sensibilities markedly affected by

In such a case, the second part of your sentence could function as an **object clause** (for more on that, [see here](http://www.icaltefl.com/object-clauses%E2%80%8F%E2%80%8E-in-english-grammar)).

> I **feel** [transitive verb] *I'm part of the world* [object clause].

Based on the definitions, the meaning could be considered different in each case. "I feel like I'm part of the world" means *I am conscious of an inward impression that relates to being part of the world*.  "I feel I'm part of the world" means *My sensibilities are deeply affected by the reality that I am part of the world.*  There is more of an implication here that you **are** part of the entity you're describing.  The first use could imply that you are not part of something but you have a deep inner impression that you are. Consider:

> I feel I'm part of the family.
>   I feel **like** I'm part of the family.

The first example sounds like a confirmation that one is part of the family and that their sensibilities are deeply affected by that, while the second example leaves more room for the reader to infer that you are not part of the family, but feel as though you are.

These distinctions are minute, and generally speaking you're safe going either way. There is quite a bit of professional writing that uses the phrase the way you describe.

[An example](http://www.nytimes.com/1987/01/03/arts/the-collage-art-of-romare-bearden-fragmented-images-of-black-life.html) from *The New York Times*:

> These are collages, and yet the artist feels he is part of the Cubist discipline.